# Condition does not imply that a sequence converges.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Show that the condition $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}$ $|a_{n+1}-a_n|=0$ is not sufficient to show that $\{a_n\}$ is convergent.

I'm having a hard time finding a counterexample. Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: how about $a_n = \sum_{k \leq n} 1 / k$

Comment: Can that be viewed as a sequence?

Comment: You’ll find at least three examples in the statement of and answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082311/how-to-prove-divergence-elementarily). See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204773/does-non-decreasing-sequence-of-this-form-converge?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

As commented, the sequence of partial sums of the harmonic series in a classic example. Another one:

$$a_n=\sqrt n\;,\;\;\text{so}\;\; \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n=\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}\le\frac1{2\sqrt n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

Answer (score 2):

Take $$a_n= \ln n$$ then $$a_{n+1}-a_n=\ln \frac{n+1}{n} \to 0$$ as $n\to \infty$ but $\{a_n\}$ does not converge.